# How to Pass tuple lists to a function arguments in python

Tags: python-3.x

I have the following code which works ok:

```
def func1():
    return Pipeline([('cont_inf_replacer', replaceInf()),
                     ])

make_column_transformer((func1(), features['cat1']),
                         (func2(), features['cat2']),
                         (func3(), features['cat3'])
)
```

Now, I would like to pass the function argument as a variable

```
func_dict = {'cat1': func1, 'cat2':func2, 'cat3': func3}
for c in features.keys():
    arg_tuple += (func_dict[c], features[c])

 make_column_transformer(arg_tuple)
```

I would expect arg_tuple should expand/unpack into

```
                         func1(), features['cat1']),
                         (func2(), features['cat2']),
                         (func2(), features['cat3'])
```

But received the following error. I did a search and could not find the proper solution

```
 ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

This is how make_column_transformer() is defined:

```
make_column_transformer(*transformers, **kwargs)
```

Unpack with *arg_tuple seems to work (no error when call make_column_transfer, but the results are different, see below)

```
make_column_transformer((func1(),features['_cat_'])): output

ColumnTransformer(n_jobs=None, remainder='drop', sparse_threshold=0.3,
     transformer_weights=None,
     transformers=[('pipeline', Pipeline(memory=None,
 steps=[('cont_inf_replacer', <__main__.replaceInf object at 0x7f87d19d6ba8>)]), ['cat1', 'cat2', 'cat3'])])
```

With *arg_tuple,

```
make_column_transformer(*arg_tuple)

ColumnTransformer(n_jobs=None, remainder='drop', sparse_threshold=0.3,
     transformer_weights=None,
     transformers=[('function', <function _pip_cont at 0x7f87d1a006a8>, ['cat1', 'cat2', 'cat3'])])
```

Comment: func2 twice`? no func3?

Comment: I am not quite sure what you are trying to achieve. Can you make a fully runable code example? What are you hoping `make_column_transformer` will do?

Comment: could you try `make_column_transformer(*arg_tuple) `?

Comment: @Onyambu, yes *arg_tuple I tried. It does not give the error with calling make_column_transformer, but it is not the same when calling the func1 directly. See my example in the above

Comment: because in your `func_dic` you have `func1` instead of `func1()` etc

Comment: @Onyambu, thanks, indeed that is the problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. make_column_transformer(*arg_tuple) will unpack ((),(),()) correctly
2. You should instead try the following

   pipline_step['cat1'] = [('test_pipeline', 
   Pipeline([SimpleImputer(xxxxxxxx)]))]
   list_pipeline = Pipeline()
   list_pipeline.steps.append(pipeline)

So in this way, instead of a for loop, you can attach the steps depending on the availability of the subsets (in this example, cat1 is available). And you can pass the subset name as a key as the pipeline steps.

Answer (score 0):

Per @onyambu, *arg_tuple solved the issue

so the following code works

```
make_column_transfer(*arg_tuple)
```

This will unpack a "list" of tuples and pass it to the function *transformers

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
def tupler(txt):
  x = eval('tuple(' + str(txt) + ')')
  print len(x)

tuple1 = (1,2,3,4,5)
string1 = str(tuple1)

tupler(string1)
```

Eval function is the trick.

For more details about eval function, [click here](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/eval)